# Circuit design for controlling Shape Memory Alloy (SMA) with a MOSFET

Tags: transistors, mosfet, batteries, circuit-design

In order to activate and deactivate the Shape Memory Alloy Flexinol LT (which activates around a current of 1,05A) I'm trying to design a circuit with a Raspberry Pi Pico W, a logic level MOSFET FQP30N06L and a 12 V battery pack.

The circuit I've designed so far looks as following:

I connected the power of the battery pack directly to one end of the SMA wire (while the GND wire of the pack is connected to a GND pin on the Raspberry). The other end of the SMA is connected to the Drain pin of the MOSFET.
The Source pin of the MOSFET is also connected to GND of the Raspberry.

I inserted a gate resistor of 100 Ω and connected the Gate to a GPIO pin of the Raspberry.
This circuit worked for once, the current activated the SMA upon activating the gate in the code. Then I tried again with the same code and now strangely nothing is happening anymore.

I've already tested the battery pack and it works when it's only connected to the wire, the current is flowing. I've also inserted a LED in front of the gate pin and it's glowing whenever I activate the gate in the code. (which means that the Raspberry pin is not broken)

Since I'm very new to electrical engineering, I'm not familiar with MOSFETs. Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with the circuit design? Also, do I need a gate-source resistor?

Comment: Drawing a schematic diagram would help illustrate your problem. You can use the schematic tool in the editor

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

The first one is the mosfet could be burned out. Get a DMM and dissconnect it from the battery and measure continuity from source to drain when it's off. It should be open impedance. If it's shorted then the gate probably blew up and you'll need a new mosfet. You could also put the meter in continuity mode and you should be able to see it switch. Another thing is the switching will need to be fast, if it's slow you could be dissipating too much power in the fet and it will burn out. Make sure the ground of the RPI is connected to the ground of the fet. A 100 ohm series resistor is fine, you could also use a 10ohm

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4rn4u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's likely that you are not sourcing enough current to the SMA wire. The 12V battery pack will need to be able to source enough current. You could put a DMM in current mode in series (make sure you use the current option that can measure amps and put the probes in the right place on the meter) and measure the current.

The best thing would be to test the wire with a bench power supply to make sure your setup is working, you could have too much resistance in series with the wire, if the SMA wire is in the 0.1 ot 0.001 Ohm range then the wire in series with the SMA wire will need to be very low resistance also, or the connect wire to the SMA will be getting all the power and not the SMA wire.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tested the Mosfet with a DMM and it works, so gate didn't blow up. I also tested my jumper wires witht the DMM and they have around 0.9 Ohm, while the resistance value of the SMA wire is around 0.035 Ohm. If I'm getting your answer correctly, this means that I should switch the jumper wire in series with a different one with a lower resistance value, right?

Comment: Yeah, if it's that low it will make a voltage divider with the SMA and take all the power. Figure out the current and then use P=I^2R to find the power. The best pet delivery you can get will be if the jumper wire resistance is equal to the SMA